# Keep calm to decipher it. What is it and what did they share?

Tags: story, steganography

Alice and Bob shared a secret key using the following story.

> Williams is a handsome boy. He is calm and brilliant. He lost his parents in an accident when they went on an uphill drive. One day, he went swimming with his five friends in a nearby river. It was autumn. His friends had gone deeper into the river but he stayed at the bank. Suddenly he heard the voices of his friends, shouting for help. He saw a large crocodile attacking them. He took a knife from his bag and jumped into the river to save them. He started fighting with the crocodile. He was wounded in the leg and wrist. The crocodile was also wounded severely by him. After a long fight, the crocodile left him and his friends brought him to the bank. All of his friends hoped that he would recover soon. Later he was rewarded for his courage by the government. The award was presented by a colonel of the US army. The colonel signed a cheque of $200 and handed it over to Williams.

Alice send to Bob another message "Keep calm to decipher it".

An intruder intercepted the message and tried to decipher it, but failed. Perhaps he is not calm. Can you decipher it?

Hint 1

> Keep silent while reading the story.

Hint 2:

> Remove unwanted things.

Comment: Please edit it if any mistakes found..

Comment: Does the rather big amount of grammatical mistakes have anything to do with the solution?

Comment: I edited it. If I in any way messed up the solution, please revert it.

Comment: @Peter  Are there any mistakes?.. Because story is important

Comment: I think the answer is much simpler than what I think it is.

Comment: @ABcDexter If you think the answer is simpler than you think then it's even simpler because you think it's simpler which means that it's simpler than that which means...

Comment: @SathiReddy erm, are the answers heading the right direction?

Comment: can you define what "silent letters" mean? standard english silent letters? what about the `l` in "williams"? Also in your second hint, can I assume I need to reassemble the answer based on some kind of pattern? or it is random?

Answer (score 1):

#### Partial answer

As hinted heavily, hidden throughout the story are

> words with silent letters:
>
> Williams is a han**d**some boy. He is ca**l**m and brilliant. He lost his parents in an accident when they went on an uphill drive. One day, he went swimming with his five fr**i**ends in a nearby river. It was autum**n**. His fr**i**ends had gone deeper into the river but he stayed at the bank. Suddenly he he**a**rd the voices of his fr**i**ends, shouting for help. He sa**w** a large crocodile attacking them. He took a **k**nife from his bag and jump**e**d into the river to save them. He started fi**gh**ting with the crocodile. He was w**o**unded in the leg and **w**rist. The crocodile was also w**o**unded severely by him. After a long fi**gh**t, the crocodile left him and his friends brought him to the bank. All of his friends hoped that he would recover soon. Later he was rewarded for his c**o**urage by the government. The award was presented by a c**olo**nel of the US army. The c**olo**nel signed a cheq**ue** of $200 and handed it over to Williams.

Some of these are debatable, but they don't really seem to spell out a message or anything - not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I would argue that some of those letters are not really silent. For example, the L in calm?

Comment: @greenturtle3141: Yeah, I wasn't sure about that one either - it depends on your accent. I've heard it both ways. (That's one of the reasons I added the disclaimer at the bottom.)

Comment: maybe after this you should use `calm` as key to decipher

Answer (score 1):

## Partial answer

What I have currently

> d e l h e e e i a n i e a e e c k e e g h e o w e l o e g h e i g h i e l e o o g h u e

And the silent letters are bolded for each sentence

> Williams is a han**d**som**e** boy. (handsome = d,e [1])

> He is ca**l**m and brilliant. (calm = l [1])

> He lost his parents in an accident w**h**en they went on an uphill driv**e**. (when = h [1]; drive = e [1])

> On**e** day, he went swimming with his fiv**e** fr**i**ends in a ne**a**rby river. (one = e [1]; five = e [1]; friends = i [3]; nearby = a [3])

> It was autum**n**. (autumn = n [1])

> His fr**i**ends had gon**e** deeper into the river but he stayed at the bank. (friends = i [3]; gone = e [1])

> Suddenly he he**a**rd the voices of his fr**i**ends, shouting for help. (heard = a [3]; friends = i [3])

> He saw a larg**e** crocodil**e** atta**c**king them. (large = e [1]; crocodile = e [1]; attacking = c [1])

> He took a **k**nif**e** from his bag and jumped into the river to sav**e** them. (knife = k,e [1]; save = e [1])

> He started fi**gh**ting with the crocodil**e**. (fighting = g,h [1]; crocodile = e [1])

> He was w**o**unded in the leg and **w**rist. (wound = o [4]; wrist = w [1])

> The crocodil**e** was a**l**so w**o**unded sever**e**ly by him. (crocodile = e [1]; also = l [1]; wounded = o [4]; severely = e [4])

> After a long fi**gh**t, the crocodil**e** left him and his fr**i**ends brou**gh**t him to the bank. (fight = g,h [1]; crocodile = e [1]; friends = i [3]; brought = g,h [1])

> All of his fr**i**ends hop**e**d that he wou**l**d recover soon. (friends = i [3]; hoped = e [1]; would = l [1])

> Later he was rewarded for his courag**e** by the government. (courage = e [1])

> The award was presented by a c**o**lonel of the US army. (colonel = o [2])

> The c**o**lonel si**g**ned a c**h**eq**ue** of $200 and handed it over to Williams. (colonel = o [2]; signed = g [1]; cheque = h [1]; cheque = u,e [3])

References:

- [1] http://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/list-of-words-with-silent-letters-in-english/
- [2]
  https://www.espressoenglish.net/silent-letters-in-english-from-a-to-z/
- [3] https://www.spellzone.com/unit22/page12.cfm
- [4] self-doubt

Comment: Answer is based on silent letters.. Please identify the correct silent letters and remove unnecessary ones to get the answer. The answer is a single word.

Comment: erm, am I finding the right silent letters?

Comment: also are two identical letters in sequence (wi**ll**iams, bri**ll**iant, t**oo**k) considered silent?